# How do I remove the search bar?

Tags: search, 1.5-cupcake

On my Android 1.5 MID, there is a Google search bar in the main screen.

- Does this have any value to me if I don't use the Internet?
- How can I remove this from the main screen?

Comment: I don't know about Android that old, but in 2.x anyway, the search bar also pulled up contacts and apps.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Long-press on the search bar; after a second or so, a trash can should appear at the top or bottom of the screen.   Drag it to the trash can.
Alternatively, you could drag it to an open space on another screen by dragging it to the left or right edge of the screen.   The screen will flip to the next panel and you can drop the widget on any open space large enough to contain it.