# How to remove the Google Now search bar from Nexus 5

Tags: stock-android, launcher, google-now, google-search

My Nexus 5 has a useless and space-wasting Google Now search bar:

[image: Ok Google]

**QUESTION: How can I remove the Google bar?**

My rooted Nexus 5 runs stock Android 5.1.1, and I would rather get rid of Google Now if possible. I would rather not use a third-party launcher.

Notes:

- Disabling Google Now bricks Nexus 5 phones, so I want a procedure which is certified to be safe on Nexus 5 explicitly.
- [This wild procedure for Nexus 5](http://trendblog.net/remove-google-search-bar-android/#comment-1693519090) is hard to trust (anonymous comment), and it requires two phones. The different procedure below does not sound more trustable.
- [Remove Google Search Bar on Nexus devices running on stock Lollipop](https://android.stackexchange.com/questions/89741/remove-google-search-bar-on-nexus-devices-running-on-stock-lollipop) is for Nexus 6 and Android 5.0. [Hide search google search bar on nexus 5](https://android.stackexchange.com/questions/66492/hide-search-google-search-bar-on-nexus-5) is different because the asker wants to keep Google Now, I don't. [How do I remove the search bar?](https://android.stackexchange.com/questions/17989/how-do-i-remove-the-search-bar) is for Android 1.5

Comment: isn't there a setting, at least in cyanogenmod is one. but I thought also on the vanilla android. but if you want, you can look for the launcher source code of the AOSP and modify it, and install it as separate launcher

Comment: Seems like you need another launcher. The search bar is most likely hard coded into your current (Google Now) launcher.

Comment: While I agree with @GiantTree (I remember the very same "hardcoded" thingy), you could try disabling *Google Now* via the *Google Settings* app. Not sure whether that helps, but it's worth a try – especially as you don't want to keep *Google Now* anyway.

Comment: Oy sh!t! Wasn't aware of that (who would dream of such a thing?) Sorry for that then. So *that* was what you meant by "the usual procedure"? Could you [edit] that into your question, and we remove the corresponding comments then?

Comment: I would like to believe that [Remove Google Search Bar on Nexus devices running on stock Lollipop](http://android.stackexchange.com/questions/89741/remove-google-search-bar-on-nexus-devices-running-on-stock-lollipop) should also work in Nexus 5, Android 5.1.1. However, the problem is, RossC's answer has been self-deleted, which I believe it should work using Xposed framework...

Comment: I was having the same problem but on Nexus 6 running stock Android 6.0.1 (yes, Google Now Launcher is there as a showpiece. The app Google seems to be handling everything and disabling it caused a boot-loop). I tried [Xposed GEL Settings](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=de.theknut.xposedgelsettings) (free) and I was able to hide that pesky search bar from home screen of Google Now Launcher. I later used GravityBox Xposed module to hide search bar from recent app screen. Try it. It should work since devices differ but not the Android version and implementation of stock launcher.

Answer (score 2):

**Added:** After more searching, I found [How to remove the Google Search bar from your Android homescreen](//trendblog.net/remove-google-search-bar-android/) indicating you have these options:

- *Disabling Google Now*, which is not recommended on the Nexus 5 as it might soft-brick your device
- *Install custom launcher*, which you don't really want to do
- *Using Xposed framework (root required)*, which doesn't seem to work as Exposed and ART is a bad combination
- *Install a custom ROM*, and then disable it

In other words, it seems like you need to make up your mind on either living with the Google Now search bar, installing a custom ROM, or install a custom launcher.

### Original answer with fails

The [14 Essential Tweaks to Perform on Your New Nexus 5 Smartphone](//www.tested.com/tech/android/459060-14-essential-tweaks-perform-your-new-nexus-5/)  has the following to say on this topic:

> You'll probably notice the search bar on the homescreen has a reminder to say "Ok Google" to trigger a voice search. It's a neat feature, but the text is a little annoying. It will go away only when you've proven you understand what it's saying. Just do any voice search from the homescreen to clear the text and get your nice, clean bar.

**Fail 1:** Does only remove the text, not the search bar

The previous tip is for the nexus 5 and lollipop,  whilst the next tip is only for previous android version,  from [25 Hidden Nexus 5 Features](//www.gottabemobile.com/2014/01/30/25-hidden-nexus-5-features/):

> Open Google Now with the quick setting above, or swipe to the left and enter Google Now on the Nexus 5. Scroll to the bottom and tap the three dots on the bottom left (menu) > tap settings > and simply tap the On/Off switch at the top to disable Google Now.

**Fail 2:** Does **only** apply to previous version of Android

My final tip if none of the above works,  I did the following on my Sony Xperia Z3 running  Android lollipop:

- long press on home screen on an empty space
- toggle the hide/show button of the Google search bar

**Fail 3:** Correct procedure for some phones, but not for Nexus 5

Hope either one of these helps you out!

Comment: I'm afraid this won't work, since it's a known "issue" that it's impossible to remove *the search box* on Nexus device. Also, the Xperia Z3's method doesn't work on Nexus since there's no setting for that.

Comment: The article you linked to says "*You'll probably notice the search bar on the homescreen has a reminder to say "Ok Google" to trigger a voice search. It's a neat feature, but the text is a little annoying. It will go away only when you've proven you understand what it's saying. Just do any voice search from the homescreen to clear the text and get your nice, clean bar.*". It is only for removing the text inside the bar, not for removing the bar itself.

Comment: @NicolasRaoul, Hmm... I was wondering about the text but it sounded so promising, that I thought I should mention it. That does render the entire answer kind of useless. Sorry.

Comment: It is not useless, at least it confirms that Google deliberately made it really hard to remove it (I am trying to do it on a more recent phone, and also failed - https://android.stackexchange.com/questions/215147/remove-search-bar-from-home-screen-in-android-9-pie ).