# Getting rid of the Google Search bar in home screen? (stock Android 5.1.1)

Tags: nexus-5, 5.1-lollipop, home-screen, google-search

I've got a Nexus 5, freshly factory reset, with stock Android 5.1.1. When searching around how to disable the Google Search bar on the Home screen, all solutions I find recommend to go Settings→Apps→All, find the 'Google Search' app and disable that. But in my App list, there is no 'Google Search'!

Yet the Google bar is most definitely on my home screen. How do I get rid of it?

Comment: [How to remove the Google Now search bar from Nexus 5](http://android.stackexchange.com/q/120733)

Answer (score 0):

I would suggest checking out action launcher 3 as a replacement to stock google now launcher, it has this option and you can keep your swipe right to get google now.

Comment: Link for the app?

Answer (score 0):

You can use any custom launcher app like [Nova](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.teslacoilsw.launcher), Apex or ADW. They will have an option to disable the Google search bar. I suggest Nova.

Answer (score 0):

[Lightning Launcher](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=net.pierrox.lightning_launcher_extreme) is also a good alternative, very fast and customisable. If you are looking for something closer to stock, try [Nova Launcher](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.teslacoilsw.launcher).

Answer (score 0):

Google Search needs to be disabled. It will not be in the first column where ordinary programs are listed. Scroll the screen sideways to the "All" column (past the "Running column) and you will find Google Search or just Search hiding somewhere. Remember what you are disabling so that you can restore it if it was the wrong app. After stopping a small disabled widget might still be there. You may need to restart the device to see it gone.